# In my apex code i'm getting hard code id error, how to resolve this type of errors?

Tags: apex, javascript

```
public SiteRegisterController () {
    }

    public String username {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String communityNickname {get; set { communityNickname = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }

    private boolean isValidPassword() {
        return password == confirmPassword;
    }

    public PageReference registerUser() {
        // it's okay if password is null - we'll send the user a random password in that case
        if (!isValidPassword()) {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            return null;
        }    
        User u = new User();
        u.Username = username;
        u.Email = email;
        u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;

        String accountId = PORTAL_ACCOUNT_ID;

        // lastName is a required field on user, but if it isn't specified, we'll default it to the username
        String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password);
        if (userId != null) { 
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                return Site.login(username, password, null);
            }
            else {
                PageReference page = System.Page.SiteRegisterConfirm;
                page.setRedirect(true);
                return page;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just don't hard code Ids. Don't you have any other way to retrieve the Id you want without hardcoding?

Comment: i don't know ho to retrieve the id in other way???                so please provide any proper solution....

Comment: see Bachovski's answer. Hope this also will help you http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_accessing.htm&language=en_US

Comment: i didn't understand where i can modified the code.. after scan the code it shows hard code id error.                          how to resolve???

Comment: any body help me regarding the hardcode id issue i'm getting     private static Id PORTAL_ACCOUNT_ID = '001x000xxx35tPN'; this error...

Answer (score 2):

Create custom settings and store the Account ID that you want to use. Then reference the custom settings field in your code. This way it's easy to manage it.

Note that if someone deletes this account your code will break.

Alternatively, query the account by Name or some other attribute(s) - if you are certain that there is always going to be 1 (the right) result.